# Recreate correct header.php using wp_nav_menu function

Tags: php, wordpress

I did a wrong action on my wordpress `header.php` file. I use a theme which is called `039-fiorellini-lilla`. I tried to re-download this theme but I can't find it anywhere on the web (this is a theme downloaded from `temi-wordpress.net` many years ago and I don't have a backup).

The problem is simple: I edited `header.php` file explicitly writing HTML code for the menu of the site.

Actually this is my header.php :

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> 
<!-- leave this for stats -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" 
type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php 
bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ? 
>/script.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>


</head>
<body onLoad="show_clock()"> 
<div class="PageBackgroundGradient"></div><div class="PageBackgroundGlare"> 
<div class="PageBackgroundGlareImage"></div></div>
<div class="Main">

<div class="Sheet">
 <div class="Sheet-body">
<div class="Header">
<div>
 &nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--START HTML CUSTOM CODE--!>
<div class="nav">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="index.htm"><a href="http://www.BLABLABLA.org/index.htm" 
tppabs="index.htm" title="Home"><span><span>Home</span></span></a></li>
<li class="index2.htm"><a class="active" 
href="http://www.BLABLABLA.org/index2.htm" tppabs="index2.htm" title="Home"> 
<span><span>Home2</span></span></a></li>
<!-- END CUSTOM HTML CODE --> 
</ul>
<div class="l"></div><div class="r"><div></div></div></div>
```

I need to recreate the correct instruction which originally were in this file to obtain the same code you can see between `<!-- START CUSTOM HTML CODE -->` and `<!-- END CUSTOM HTML CODE -->`.
I think that probably I must use wp_nav_menu function but I have great problem to implement it. In this site I have only 1 menu of navigation which is called NAVIGATION1.
I need also that parameters class="active" remains active on the web pages actually visualized.

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem of the correct links of the menu using this code :

```
     <ul class="menu">
     <?php wp_list_pages("link_before=<span><span>&title_li=&depth=1'&&    link_after=</span></span>");?>
     </ul>
     <div class="l"></div><div class="r"><div></div></div></div>
```

and it works fine.
I did some test using this functions :

```
    add_filter('wp_list_pages', create_function('$t', 'return str_replace("<a ", "<a class=\"ACTIVE\" ", $t);'));
```

And it's works correctly but it sets the attribute ACTIVE to all the pages of the menu while I need that this attribute is set only to active page of first level (no child page) of the menu (the page that is visualized in that moment.)

Probably, another possible solution is to use the class .current-menu-item wich is added to the menu item for the current page being viewed by the user but I have problem to modify my .css file to add the correct attribute for this class.
I said before that I need that current page has the same behaviour of the hovered page (same color, same font. etc etc).
This is a portion of my .css file for the hover :

```
elemento {
}
.menu li:hover a span span {
    color: #131112;
    background-position: left -24px;
}
.menu a:hover span span {
    color: #131112;
    background-position: left -24px;
}
.menu li:hover a span {
    background-position: right -24px;
}
.menu a:hover span {
    background-position: right -24px;
}
.menu a span span {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EFD2E0;
    margin: 0 1px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('images/item-center.png');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.menu a span {
    background-image: url('images/item-right.png');
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.menu a, .menu a span {
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
}
.menu a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
     color: #000090;
}
 a:link {
     color: #87315B;
 }
 a {
     color: #87315B;
 }
 .menu li:hover {
     white-space: normal;
 }
 .menu, .menu ul {
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 .Sheet-body {
    text-align: left;
 }
 body {
     font-size: 62.5%;
     font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, 
     Sans-Serif;
     color: #000000;
  }
```

The portion of HTML code generated is :

```
...
...
....<li class="page_item page-item-36 ***current_page_item***"><li><span 
....class="separator"></span></li><a href="http://BLABLA.com/"><span> 
.....<span>index.htmk</span></span></a></li>
...
...
```

Can someone help me to modify my .cssto add the portion of code for the active page?
Thanks